# AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libandroidicu.so" not found

Tags: android, android-library, android-native-library

I am using a Google Pixel 2 running Android 10. The mobile is rooted.

When I install my app its giving the error ***AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libandroidicu.so" not found***

So I looked for **libandroidicu.so in /system/lib/** but its not present there.

From where can I get this **libandroidicu.so** file?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the ndk version can help

The same problem on github has a solution: https://github.com/google/oboe/issues/421